# mysql search for % and $ characters no results

Tags: php, mysql, search

```
 $word ="50%";
 $searchSQL = "SELECT * FROM discounts WHERE keyword LIKE '%$word%' ";
```

when I execute this query it returns no results.
I assume the issue is the % sign which is a wild card in mysql.
what would be the correct way to search for that $word

Answer (score 3):

try something like this,

```
 $word ="50%";
 $searchSQL = "SELECT * FROM discounts WHERE keyword LIKE '%$word%' escape '%'";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection` if the value(*s*) came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using PreparedStatements you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: yeah I have $keyword mysql escape string and strip_tags to avoid that.

Comment: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: +1 ...and [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/1723893) in comment link is better than votest  in **How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?**

Answer (score 2):

You try to search the `%`? If not, change `keyword = '%$word%'` to `keyword LIKE '%$word%'`.
If you do, escape the `%` with: `LIKE '50\%' ESCAPE '\'":`

```
$word ="50\\%";
$searchSQL = "SELECT * FROM discounts WHERE keyword LIKE '%$word%' ESCAPE '\' ";
```

Comment: this is perfect didnt know you could escape using sql.I was going to use the php addslashes();

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a leading slash before special chars when doing a query in MySQL. So like this:

```
$word = "50\\%";
```

Comment: what if it comes from a form ?

Comment: yes. When using special chars like % you have to add leading slash.